# Load properties from file in runtime in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, properties, runtime

I have Flex application in which I want to load properties from file during runtime.
For example: I want to have email address to application administrator and I do not want to rebuild application every time administrator changes. I want to make change in properties file and application should load updated value.

I have found tutorials for loading localizations in runtime, but this is not quite what I need.
Any help (and sample code) will be appreciated.

PS.
If this makes any difference my application is compiled under Flex 3.5

Comment: Just put a JSON or XML file on the server, download it and parse it. Do you have a specific issue?

Comment: Why I need to download file? And also parse it by myself? I want to place it with application (like Spring properties file)

Comment: A Flex app runs on the client machine (unlike a classic - possibly Spring-based - web app), so the only way to read properties at runtime is to have the Flex app download the properties file on the client machine and read it.

Comment: @RIAstar Thank you for this clarification. Is there any standard method of parsing configuration files or do I have to parse it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to load the external properties files using an URLLoader object and then parse the properties. For the parsing, you can use the StringUtils.parseProperties method from [AS3Commons-Lang](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-lang/)

```
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, urlLoaderCompleteHandler);

var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
urlLoader.load(request);

private function urlLoaderCompleteHandler(event:Event):void {
  var properties:Object = StringUtils.parseProperties(urlLoader.data);
}
```

Comment: Didn't know you had a .properties parser in there: good to know.

Answer (score 3):

To complement @Christophe's answer: there are two ways of doing the parsing natively (i.e. no third-party library required), but none of them parses .properties file.

## JSON

(**warning**: only available natively as of Flash Player 11)

Write your config file in json format:

```
{
    "myProperty": "myValue",
    "otherProp": "someValue"
}
```

Load it the same way Christophe describes and handle like this:

```
private function urlLoaderCompleteHandler(event:Event):void {
    var properties:Object = JSON.parse(urlLoader.data);
    trace(properties.myProperty); //myValue
}
```

## XML

Write your config file in XML format:

```
<config>
    <myProperty>myValue</myProperty>
    <otherProp value="someValue"/>
</config>
```

Load it the same way Christophe describes and handle like this:

```
private function urlLoaderCompleteHandler(event:Event):void {
    var properties:XML= XML(urlLoader.data);
    trace(properties.myProperty.text()); //myValue
    trace(properties.otherProp.@value); //someValue
}
```